# How to send large amount of Data To SqlServer Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlbulkcopy

I want to send large amounts of data from a .Net based application to the SQL Server. This Data Records are coming from a CSV file and should be funneled through a Stored Procedure on the SQL Server side. I know about SqlBulkCopy but SqlBulklCopy writes directly to tables. Means, it is not usable for me. I am speaking from over 100.000.000 Records. I won't be able to hold this amount of data in memory. So ideally I ask if there exists some kind of streaming Data from .Net to a Stored Procedure. I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Look for `DataTable` and `user defined table types`.

Comment: Why don't you chop the data into smaller portions and import them sequentially? This would also allow for some progress feedback in your frontend.

Comment: Did you considered Sql Server Integration Services?

Comment: describe the problem and not the solution. you ruled out bulk copy for unknown reasons, are not willing to use (temp?) tables for unknown reasons. what are you going to do with 100M rows without storing them in tables?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri We don't want to use SSIS for different Reasons.

Comment: @Robert This could be one option. I just thought there is something what is not on my radar but worth knowing.

Comment: @Paolo With SqlBulkCopy you need to precreate a table on the database to import the data. The CSV data I have to import can have an unknown amount of column count and types. Of course there is the option to create a temporary table before the Bulk import. I just want to know if there is a streaming possibility which can go through StoredProcedure argument or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are seeking for [Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx). There is enough documentation how to create TVP type in the database and use it inside a stored procedure. When setting up a `SqlParameter`, you can supply `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` which can easily be provided by a C# iterator function directly reading sequentially CSV file data records one by one and for each record, parse, convert and yield a corresponding `SqlDataRecord`. At the Sql Server side the data will still be bulk inserted into a tempdb before passed to the stored procedure, but at least at client side you don't need a memory to hold all that data.

Comment: Looks like that's the way to go without using BulkCopy.